# How many ways can racers finish the race.

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can racers finish the race in top 20 if we know there were 5 racers from team A, 4 from team B, 3 from team C, 3 from team D, 2 from team E, 2 from team F and 1 from team G. We do not care about names of racers only about team they represent with one exception: team D in which we make difference between racers and we know 5 of them started race and only 3 made top20.

Comment: How many ways to place the $A$s?  Having done that, there are $15$ slots left.  How many ways to place the $B$s?

Comment: So i always pick 5 places out of 20, then multiply it by 4 places out of 15 and so on? And at the end i can just choose 3 racers out of 5 for the team D using variations?

Comment: Yes, you multiply it as you say.  You only have three racers from $D$ in the list.  The fact that five racers from $D$ entered does not matter because we only care what team they come from.